# Symfony2 FormBuilder isn't rendering text fields

Tags: symfony, twig, formbuilder

I'm using Symfony's [FormBuilder](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/forms.html) to create a form and render it via Twig.

I use this as my Type:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

class RequestType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text');
        $builder->add('email', 'email');
        $builder->add('question', 'textarea');

    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array('data_class' => 'Vendor\\AppBundle\\App\\Request');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of this type.
     *
     * @return string The name of this type
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'request';
    }
}
```

When I render my form (with `form_widget(form.field)`) everything looks great, except for the `name` field, that doesn't output any input field. If I change to something like "email", it works perfectly.

I'm using Sf2.3 BETA 1. Any thoughts on why does this happen with text fields only? It's woth noting that the labels, fieldsets, and everything is outputted, except the actual `<input>` tag.

**EDIT 1:** [This](http://pastebin.com/CKBzYd0r) is the Controller Code, in case you need it.

**EDIT 2:** It's worth noticing that this is an update from a Sf2.1 app to Sf2.3 BETA 1. The code has been updated, but perhaps something's wrong with that?

Comment: In the HTML rendered by the server you have no input field even hidden? Can you show us your controller code?

Comment: @cheesemacfly No, not even hidden. The Controller code is [this](http://pastebin.com/CKBzYd0r) — nothing too fancy. I still don't get what's the deal.

Comment: And how is the class `appRequest` defined?

Comment: @cheesemacfly Nothing too fancy — just a couple of getters and setters (3 and 3 total, return only properties). Weird thing is that it happens with **every** instance of the FormBuilderInterface. No matter what controller or class I use, I end up not having text fields.

Comment: That's weird...can you try to do `$builder->add('name')` (removing the `text` type)?

Comment: @cheesemacfly Nope, nothing — that's the default and it does nothing.

Comment: And if you add another text field does it work or is it the same behavior for any text field? Can you show us your twig template?

Comment: @cheesemacfly Yes, if I add another field still does the same thing. No matter what the name is. This is the template: http://pastebin.com/Hbbymih5 — I don't see anything relevant there :/

Comment: I just tested with Symfony 2.2 and can't reproduce...do you have a way to test with a earlier version?

Comment: You dont have specific CSS that can hide that field?

Comment: @Ninsuo No — the field doesn't appear in the markup at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it was something that had to do with the fact that this code is a refactor of really old (+2 years) code.

The issue was that the [form widget was being replaced with another one](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_customization.html), and that "other one" was messing with the output, since Twig's functions aren't the same, nor the structure.